# How to sort the filenames shown in grep command based on timestamp?

Tags: grep, ksh, sort, timestamps

In the following command, how can I get the file names based on its timestamp

```
$ grep "exit 0" a*
a1.txt:+ exit 0
a2.txt:+ exit 0
a3.txt:+ exit 0
a4.txt:+ exit 0
a5.txt:+ exit 0

$ ls -latr 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user grp  83046 Oct 27 06:46 a5.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user grp  68108 Oct 27 07:59 a1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user grp 159792 Oct 27 12:35 a2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user grp 225703 Oct 27 16:41 a3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user grp 246782 Oct 27 20:17 a4.txt
```

As you see the above output, I am not getting the output based on the timestamp the file was created. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If none of the file names contain space, tab, newline (and `$IFS` has not been modified), `?`, `*`, `[` characters or are called `-`, this should do it:

```
grep -- "exit 0" $(ls -tr a*)
```

`$()` is called command substitution. Your shell will first run `ls -tr`, then split+glob its output to make up the list of files passed to your `grep` command.

Comment: Omni, I noticed that your command also displays the output from unmatched files also.  For eg.  I am trying to grep on a*.txt, but it gives the output on b*txt too.  why is it so?

Comment: Sorry it was my bad.  Instead of doing, grep "exit 0" $(ls -tr a*), i was doing - grep "exit 0" a* $(ls -tr)

Comment: @Gilles, `--` doesn't protect against a file called `-`.

Comment: @janani I'm glad you caught that. I'd meant to include a* in my command to match your example. I'll update the answer for future generations.

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell, you can affect the order of globs with *glob qualifiers*.

```
grep 'exit 0' a*(.Om)
```

`Om` is to reverse o⃞rder by m⃞odification time. I also added .⃞ to select only *regular* files (not *directories* or *pipes* or *devices* or *symlinks*...).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks Omni.  Even the following way, I am able to achieve this.  Of course urs is the simple one.  thanks a lot

```
       grep -H "exit 0" /opt/ctmagent/ctm/sysout_archives/141027/d_dms_btch_alrt_ifm_scp_ksh* | awk -F":" '{system("ls -latr "$1"")}'
```

Comment: That runs one `ls` per file, so is not going to do anything wrt sorting. That also interprets the file name as shell code so is very dangerous.